# TFS vs Azure Devops Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Hope someone can help.

I am looking for some sort of diagram / info on the evolution of the TFS 2015/2018 componets.

What I mean is, I have read online that Azure Devops Server is made up of:

Azure Pipeline,
Azure Repos,
Azure Boards,
Azure Test Plans,
Azure Arifacts

I'm looking for a diagram that would show if these components come from TFS (before it became Azure Deveops). If so, what were they called in TFS.  Or if they are new and if any other component from TFS did not get carried over.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Devops Server is a new release version of TFS(Team Foundation Server).There is no difference in nature. At the basic level, it's still the same function. What you're confused about like `Azure Pipeline`, `Azure Repos`, `Azure Boards`, `Azure Test Plans`, `Azure Arifacts` are from [Azure Devops Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/#overview).

These components are first released by Azure Devops Services. It is just in use that adding these functions on services to Azure Devops Server(actually from TFS2018) makes the user experience more convenient and more efficient. That's why it has this feature.

Comment: Thanks Perry. Just to make sure I understand correctly. So TFS 2019 (Azure Devops Server) is the updated version of TFS 2018. Basically the same. Azure Pipeline, Azure Repos, Azure Boards, Azure Test Plans, Azure Arifacts are components for Azure Devops Services. Are these components also available to Azure Devops Server or are they already part of Azure Devops Server?

Comment: @Next1On It's all branding. The source control component of TFS was renamed to "Azure Repos".  It's still part of Azure DevOps Server. There are no new, separate products or services. It's all the same stuff as it always has been.